# Create New Folder in Google Drive from Google Sheets (Apps Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to run a script in Google Sheets that creates a new folder in Google Drive within a given parent folder (which already exists).  The new folder name should be drawn directly from text within a specified cell 'A2'.

I've tried a few different scripts with no success.  Any help would be very appreciated!

here's what I had so far...

```
function createFolderBasic(folderID, folderName) {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var newFolder = folder.createFolder(folderName);
  return newFolder.getId();
};

function start(){
  //Add your own folder ID here:
  var FOLDER_ID = 'my folder id';
  //Add the name of your folder here:
  var NEW_FOLDER_NAME = "new folder name";
  var myFolderID = createFolderBasic(FOLDER_ID, NEW_FOLDER_NAME);
  Logger.log(myFolderID);
};
```

Comment: Your script works on my side. Did you allow your script to access the DriveApp? and have you got the correct parent folder id?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of precedents for this question on Stack Exchange, but you a specific need and it is better to help you out than refer to to another script.

This is a new script:

```
function makeFolder(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)

  var newFolderName = sheet.getRange("A2").getValue()
  Logger.log("The new Foider will be called:"+newFolderName)
  
  var parentFolderID = "<<insert folder ID>>"
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderID)

  var newFolderID = parentFolder.createFolder(newFolderName).getId()
  Logger.log("The ID of the new folder is "+newFolderID)
}
```

---

**Things to note:**

- You have a spreadsheet with a folder name in cell "A2".

  - Open the Project Editor for that spreadsheet
  - Save this script in the Project.
- Get the ID of the Parent Folder for your new folder (use Google Drive).

  - Insert this ID between the quotation marks on `var parentFolderID = "<<insert folder ID>>"`